# Continue building Docker image after error occured

Tags: docker

I have a Dockerfile that install Ubuntu and some packages over it and then proceeds to use these packages. Let's say I need to run 'wget' command, but forgot to issue install of the 'wget' package. I add the package to install command and continue with my execution. However I have to start over - install Ubuntu, install package, etc., or do I? Is there ability to save what I did until error occurred and continue from that point after I did my fixes instead of downloading everything again?

Comment: Sometimes for this instance you might want to subdivide your build into a sequence of images. Each successive step picks up the previous step at the FROM command.

Comment: If you re-run `docker build` it will essentially skip over steps it's already done.  See for example ["Leverage build cache" in "Best practices for writing Dockerfiles" in the Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#leverage-build-cache).

Comment: @DavidMaze That's interesting because it looks like every time I build my docker, it's starts fresh. May be I am not issues enough commands? As I understand cache is automatic. Here is my Dockerfile https://github.com/akravets/bus-notify/blob/master/Dockerfile

Comment: Any time anything changes, none of the later steps will be cached.  Since you have `COPY . /camera` very early in the Dockerfile, the following `RUN apt-get ...` becomes non-cacheable if anything changes at all in your source tree.  I'd move that to later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes for this instance you might want to subdivide your build into a chain of images. Each successive step picks up the previous step at the FROM command.

Answer (score 0):

Just to point out that David Maze's answer was most appropriate for my case:

> Any time anything changes, none of the later steps will be cached. Since you have COPY . /camera very early in the Dockerfile, the following RUN apt-get ... becomes non-cacheable if anything changes at all in your source tree. I'd move that to later.

This is what I had COPY command in a wrong place, which really makes sense - I copy everything docker accumulated before resolving what I needed so I ended executing all directives after COPY every time I build the image. After I moved COPY down as David suggested, all the cached data was there.